# How to Build a Summary Table Connecting Communities in a Hierarchical Community Graph Plot

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Working from the code below, how can the table it generates produce these results for the hierarchical community (where there are 6 communities given by common node color) instead of the 5 communities produced?

```
edges = {NS <-> N1, NS <-> N11, NS <-> N18, NS <-> N24, NS <-> N27, 
   NS <-> N35, NS <-> N37, N1 <-> N4, N1 <-> N5, N1 <-> N6, N1 <-> N7,
    N1 <-> N8, N1 <-> N9, N2 <-> N5, N3 <-> N5, N3 <-> N15, N4 <-> N2,
    N4 <-> N3, N4 <-> N5, N4 <-> N12, N4 <-> N13, N4 <-> N14, 
   N5 <-> N15, N5 <-> N16, N5 <-> N19, N6 <-> N15, N7 <-> N10, 
   N8 <-> N16, N9 <-> N10, N10 <-> N5, N10 <-> N6, N10 <-> N8, 
   N11 <-> N6, N11 <-> N8, N11 <-> N21, N12 <-> N17, N12 <-> N40, 
   N13 <-> N6, N13 <-> N21, N14 <-> NG, N15 <-> N30, N16 <-> N6, 
   N17 <-> NG, N18 <-> N15, N19 <-> N20, N20 <-> N21, N20 <-> N30, 
   N21 <-> N22, N22 <-> N23, N22 <-> N43, N23 <-> NG, N24 <-> NG, 
   N25 <-> NG, N26 <-> N29, N26 <-> N40, N27 <-> N28, N27 <-> N40, 
   N28 <-> NG, N29 <-> NG, N30 <-> N31, N30 <-> N32, N30 <-> N33, 
   N30 <-> N34, N31 <-> N36, N32 <-> N36, N33 <-> N36, N34 <-> N31, 
   N35 <-> N34, N36 <-> N12, N36 <-> N39, N37 <-> N36, N38 <-> N40, 
   N38 <-> N43, N39 <-> N40, N40 <-> N41, N41 <-> N42, N42 <-> NG, 
   N43 <-> N25, N43 <-> N26, N36 <-> N38};

g = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
  VertexSize -> 0.9, VertexLabelStyle -> 14, 
  VertexStyle -> {NS | N1 | N11 | N18 | N24 | N27 | N35 -> 
     Darker[Red], N37 | N4 | N5 | N6 | N7 | N8 | N9 -> Red, 
    N2 | N3 | N15 | N12 | N13 -> Lighter[Lighter[Orange]], 
    N14 | N16 | N19 | N10 | N21 | N17 | N40 -> Yellow, 
    NG | N30 | N20 | N22 | N23 | N43 | N25 | N26 | N29 | N28 | N31 -> 
     Darker[Green], 
    N32 | N33 | N34 | N36 | N39 | N38 | N41 | N42 -> Lighter[Green]}]

cg = CommunityGraphPlot[g, 
  VertexStyle -> {v_ :> PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexStyle]}]
communities = 
  GatherBy[VertexList[g], PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexStyle] &];
CommunityGraphPlot[g, communities, 
  VertexStyle -> PropertyValue[g, VertexStyle]];
CommunityGraphPlot[g, communities, Method -> "Hierarchical", 
 VertexStyle -> PropertyValue[g, VertexStyle]]

ClearAll[connectingEdgesF, tabulateF]
connectingEdgesF = 
  Module[{g = #}, 
    Complement[EdgeList[#], 
     Flatten[EdgeList[Subgraph[g, #]] & /@ 
       FindGraphCommunities[g]]]] &;
tabulateF = 
  Module[{rule = 
      Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[# -> #2[[1]]] &, 
        FindGraphCommunities[#], 1], edges = connectingEdgesF[#]}, 
    TableForm[(List @@@ edges) /. {a_, b_} :> 
       Join[{a, a /. rule}, {b, b /. rule}], 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"From Vertex", "in Community", 
        "To Vertex", "in Community"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]] &;
connectingEdgesF[g];
tabulateF[g]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `communities` instead of `FindGraphCommunities[g]` when you define `connectingEdgesF`:

```
ClearAll[connectingEdgesF, tabulateF]
connectingEdgesF = Module[{g = #}, 
    Complement[EdgeList[g], Flatten[EdgeList[Subgraph[g, #]] & /@ communities]]] &;

tabulateF = Module[{rule = Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[# -> #2[[1]]] &, communities, 1], 
     edges = connectingEdgesF[#]}, 
    TableForm[(List @@@ edges) /. {a_, b_} :> 
       Join[{a, a /. rule}, {b, b /. rule}], 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"From Vertex", "in Community", 
        "To Vertex", "in Community"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]] &;

tabulateF[g] // TeXForm
```

> $\small\begin{array}{cccc}
>  \text{From Vertex} & \text{in Community} & \text{To Vertex} & \text{in Community} \\
>  \text{N1} & 1 & \text{N4} & 2 \\
>  \text{N1} & 1 & \text{N5} & 2 \\
>  \text{N1} & 1 & \text{N6} & 2 \\
>  \text{N1} & 1 & \text{N7} & 2 \\
>  \text{N1} & 1 & \text{N8} & 2 \\
>  \text{N1} & 1 & \text{N9} & 2 \\
>  \text{N10} & 4 & \text{N5} & 2 \\
>  \text{N10} & 4 & \text{N6} & 2 \\
>  \text{N10} & 4 & \text{N8} & 2 \\
>  \text{N11} & 1 & \text{N21} & 4 \\
>  \text{N11} & 1 & \text{N6} & 2 \\
>  \text{N11} & 1 & \text{N8} & 2 \\
>  \text{N12} & 3 & \text{N17} & 4 \\
>  \text{N12} & 3 & \text{N40} & 4 \\
>  \text{N13} & 3 & \text{N21} & 4 \\
>  \text{N13} & 3 & \text{N6} & 2 \\
>  \text{N14} & 4 & \text{NG} & 5 \\
>  \text{N15} & 3 & \text{N30} & 5 \\
>  \text{N16} & 4 & \text{N6} & 2 \\
>  \text{N17} & 4 & \text{NG} & 5 \\
>  \text{N18} & 1 & \text{N15} & 3 \\
>  \text{N19} & 4 & \text{N20} & 5 \\
>  \text{N2} & 3 & \text{N5} & 2 \\
>  \text{N20} & 5 & \text{N21} & 4 \\
>  \text{N21} & 4 & \text{N22} & 5 \\
>  \text{N24} & 1 & \text{NG} & 5 \\
>  \text{N26} & 5 & \text{N40} & 4 \\
>  \text{N27} & 1 & \text{N28} & 5 \\
>  \text{N27} & 1 & \text{N40} & 4 \\
>  \text{N3} & 3 & \text{N5} & 2 \\
>  \text{N30} & 5 & \text{N32} & 6 \\
>  \text{N30} & 5 & \text{N33} & 6 \\
>  \text{N30} & 5 & \text{N34} & 6 \\
>  \text{N31} & 5 & \text{N36} & 6 \\
>  \text{N34} & 6 & \text{N31} & 5 \\
>  \text{N35} & 1 & \text{N34} & 6 \\
>  \text{N36} & 6 & \text{N12} & 3 \\
>  \text{N37} & 2 & \text{N36} & 6 \\
>  \text{N38} & 6 & \text{N40} & 4 \\
>  \text{N38} & 6 & \text{N43} & 5 \\
>  \text{N39} & 6 & \text{N40} & 4 \\
>  \text{N4} & 2 & \text{N12} & 3 \\
>  \text{N4} & 2 & \text{N13} & 3 \\
>  \text{N4} & 2 & \text{N14} & 4 \\
>  \text{N4} & 2 & \text{N2} & 3 \\
>  \text{N4} & 2 & \text{N3} & 3 \\
>  \text{N40} & 4 & \text{N41} & 6 \\
>  \text{N42} & 6 & \text{NG} & 5 \\
>  \text{N5} & 2 & \text{N15} & 3 \\
>  \text{N5} & 2 & \text{N16} & 4 \\
>  \text{N5} & 2 & \text{N19} & 4 \\
>  \text{N6} & 2 & \text{N15} & 3 \\
>  \text{N7} & 2 & \text{N10} & 4 \\
>  \text{N8} & 2 & \text{N16} & 4 \\
>  \text{N9} & 2 & \text{N10} & 4 \\
>  \text{NS} & 1 & \text{N37} & 2 \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: I was close! ... again, many thanks kglr ... I've learned much from your help ... prg

Comment: @PRG, you're welcome. Thank you for accepting.